# Simple Regex Help

Tags: regex, linux, apache

I'm struggling to create a regex for Apache logs. The log format I'm using is below.

I'd like to be able to match ANY word or phrase where "/city/index.html" is.

`66-121-89-14.domain.com - - [14/Apr/2011:14:47:05 +0100] "GET /city/index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 2577 "http://www.domain.com/referrer/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110319 Firefox/3.6.16"`

Can a regex ace please help ?

--edit--

It's for ignoreregex on Fail2ban. I'd really like to be able to put something like `/house` to catch all files in that directory or also `/house/jonross.html` specifically to match just that HTML file.  Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps but I had noticed that Google refine has canned help for parsing Apache logs http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/ watch the videos, very easy to use

Comment: how do you define a phrase? are you using grep? do you want to match any line with `/city/index.html` or do you want to do more?

Comment: Do you need to limit your search to particular columns? If not, I'm not sure why you need a regex. A simple 'string.Contains' on the line should do the trick... unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Sorry, I want to be able to put something like `/house`to catch all files in that directory or also `/house/jonross.html` specifically to match just that HTML file.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. It's for Fail2ban if that makes any difference as 'ignoreregex'.

Answer (score 1):

If by "phrase" you mean "line" then that would be `^.*/city/index\.html.*$` in multiline mode.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^.*\/city\/index.html.*$/g
```

This will match any line containing the path /city/index.html

Comment: I probably should have been clearer, sorry, it's late. It's for Fail2ban if that makes any difference as 'ignoreregex'. Please see comments above.

Answer (score 1):

`/"\w+ (.*?) HTTP\//` will capture the URL of the request.

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of trial and hour, in case it helps someone else, this will ignore any directory after the slash after GET with these words:

`ignoreregex = .*\"GET \/(city|house|anything).*`

For `.html` the dot needs escaped.